# Azure kafka trigger exposing Autooffset property in KafkaOptions

Tags: c#, azure, apache-kafka, azure-functions, kafka-consumer-api

I am a beginner to Azure kafka trigger and learning how to use it.
Can someone kindly give a sample of how to use the **KafkaOptions.AutoOffsetReset** when using the Azure Kafka trigger.

I have truly looking for a example but couldn’t find any?

I cannot add the property in kafka trigger but i need the property in my Azure kafka trigger. How do i add it?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-kafka-extension#net-quickstart) documentation, you can add this configuration in your `host.json` file:

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "kafka": {
      "maxBatchSize": 100,
      "auto.offset.reset": "latest"
    }
  }
}
```

Check some samples [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-kafka-extension/tree/dev/samples/dotnet).

The [KafkaTriggerAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-kafka-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cconfluent&pivots=programming-language-csharp#attributes) itself does not expose an autooffset property.